# How to sort list by 2 columns

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a list created from a log file and I need to sort it.

I have tried `list.OrderBy()` but it gives me errors and is not working.

```
List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();
var logFile = File.ReadAllLines(Name1);
foreach (var item in logFile)
{
   list.Add(new string[] { date_check(item), time_check(item),logType(item), device(item), rest(item) });
}
```

I need to sort this list by date and time. How can I do it?

Comment: Can you update your question with which type of error generated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try like this

```
 var sortList = list.OrderBy(a => a.date_check).ThenBy(a => a.time_check).ToList();
```

Comment: i get this error : Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'date_check' and no extension method 'date_check' accepting a first argument of type 'string[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Logs Analizer C:\Users\HajduSl\source\repos\Logs Analizer\Logs Analizer\LogFileView.cs 31 Active

Comment: found it : var sortList = list.OrderBy(arr => arr[0]).ThenBy(arr => arr[1]).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

acording to Vinoth answer this one worked for me:

```
var sortList = list.OrderBy(arr => arr[0]).ThenBy(arr => arr[1]).ToList();
```